# Dask: Access published dataset from within a submitted job

Tags: pandas, dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

```
# Init
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client()
```

```
# Publish data
dataset_name = 'my_dataset'
df_my_dataset = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((2,3)), dtype=np.float32)
client.publish_dataset(df_my_dataset, name=dataset_name)
```

Its there:

```
In [13]: client.list_datasets()                                                                                                           
Out[13]: ('my_dataset',)
```

Create submit function for dask. Here I would like to access the published dataset by name:

```
# submit function
def get_gate1_rows(df_from_submit):
    return df_from_submit.mean()
    # return df.mean() + my_dataset.mean() #### <<<<<<< How to do this?
```

And finally the submit:

```
# Submit code
df_zeros = np.zeros((2,3), dtype=np.float32)
future = client.submit(get_gate1_rows, df_zeros)
time.sleep(2)
result = future.result()
```

This yields - but should be `0.5`:

```
In [41]: result                                                                                                                           
Out[41]: 0.0
```

So how can I access the `published dataset` from **within** the dask job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the published datasets within a task, you need [`get_client`](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/api.html#distributed.get_client):

```
def get_gate1_rows(df_from_submit):
    client = distributed.get_client()
    my_dataset = client.get_dataset('my_dataset')
    return df_from_submit.mean() + my_dataset.mean()
```

(the answer is three 1s, since df_zeros.mean()->0, df_my_dataset.mean()->1,1,1)

Comment: hehe - nice catch for pointing out the mistake. ;) Will try it this evening. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: [Can also be used in `with` statement](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/task-launch.html#connection-with-context-manager)